# 19.10: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 WiFi works on one network out of many

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, atheros

**Update:** Not a solution, but I bought an Intel Wireless-ac 9260 and installed it. No problems and everything works out of the box. Also, the speeds are higher.

Until recently, I had no problems with wifi on that machine for years (through few Ubuntu upgrades). Then suddenly my wifi started dropping out after a few seconds of activity on any network (work, airport, cafes etc.) except for one of the two networks at home, which is just the original network at home, but through a wifi booster.

I have updated my firmware, as suggested in many other questions on this topic and in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1743279). I copied the whole QCA6174 folder from the **kvalo** repository and copied it over (after deleting my QCA6174 folder) and renamed the newest available firmware file in `hw3.0` to **firmware-6.bin** and similarly for **firmware-5.bin** in `hw2.1` (not sure whether I need the latter). Still same issues.

Here is some information (I am using Ubuntu 19.10)

```
uname -r

5.4.13-050413-generic
```

and

```
lsmod | grep ath10k

ath10k_pci             49152  0
ath10k_core           466944  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    36864  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              843776  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              704512  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
```

and

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath10k

3b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0a1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Device [0707:2400]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
--
3c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
[    3.021542] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.022690] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.309998] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[    3.310001] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    3.310580] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1.c3-00059 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad,raw-mode,mfp crc32 3c85e1f9
[    3.376446] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 c15a244d
[    3.442816] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[    3.460443] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: htt-ver 3.62 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    3.542738] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0 wlp60s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.639915] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[    6.003341] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[  338.455559] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: firmware crashed! (guid e0db7bbf-9872-4b3c-b90f-625d2aac258d)
[  338.455572] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535
[  338.455576] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[  338.457093] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1.c3-00059 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad,raw-mode,mfp crc32 3c85e1f9
[  338.458371] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 c15a244d
[  338.458378] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: htt-ver 3.62 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[  338.458518] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: firmware register dump:
[  338.458524] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [00]: 0x05030000 0x00000000 0x00950A7C 0x0059CB04
[  338.458529] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [04]: 0x00950A7C 0x00070030 0x00000000 0x000A68A8
[  338.458533] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [08]: 0x004479B4 0x004481A6 0x00080805 0x0040E788
[  338.458537] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [12]: 0x00000000 0xFFFFFFFF 0x00952CD0 0x00952CE6
[  338.458541] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [16]: 0x809A9637 0x0040E788 0x00404D00 0x2A05C000
[  338.458545] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [20]: 0x00000002 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0046E7B8
[  338.458549] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [24]: 0x809ED6BF 0x0040E7C8 0x00423C1C 0xC09ED90B
[  338.458553] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [28]: 0x009ED90B 0x00060330 0x00000000 0x2A0BD3C0
[  338.458557] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [32]: 0x0044AC60 0x0040E7E8 0x00000002 0x0059CAF8
[  338.458561] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [36]: 0x00000003 0xFFFFFFFF 0x00952CD0 0x00952CE6
[  338.458564] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [40]: 0xDD36F468 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x000A68A8
[  338.458568] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [44]: 0x809EC16A 0x0040E7F8 0x00000010 0x00423C1C
[  338.458572] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [48]: 0x809EA597 0x0040E7E8 0x0044819E 0x00000000
[  338.458576] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [52]: 0xDD36FA38 0x0049E860 0x00000001 0x004127C0
[  338.458580] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [56]: 0x809EC88D 0x0040E868 0x0041293C 0x0044841C
[  338.458583] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
[  338.458595] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400  11  11   3   3
[  338.458606] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800   4   4 113 114
[  338.458617] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00  31  31  94  95
[  338.458627] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000  14  14  16  14
[  338.458638] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 4439 4431 231 169
[  338.458648] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800   0   0  64   0
[  338.458659] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00  30  30  17  17
[  338.458669] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000   1   1   1   1
[  338.759678] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[  338.844045] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device successfully recovered
[  433.373584] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[  433.373591] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to stop scan: -110
[  433.373594] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -110
[  447.457365] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: wmi command 12289 timeout, restarting hardware
[  447.457375] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -11
[  447.543417] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device has crashed during init
[  447.571507] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device has crashed during init
[  447.571512] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to wait for target init: -70
[  447.778890] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
[  447.858685] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device successfully recovered
[  573.917228] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to receive scan abortion completion: timed out
[  573.917240] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to abort scan: -110
[  585.185372] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: wmi command 24579 timeout, restarting hardware
[  585.185452] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 1 ar-state 1): 1250
[  585.267074] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to delete peer 48:d3:43:67:6a:d7 for vdev 0: -108
[  585.267257]  snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt snd_hda_codec crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_core snd_hwdep crc32_pclmul snd_pcm mei_hdcp ghash_clmulni_intel intel_rapl_msr snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi ath10k_pci ath10k_core i915 snd_seq ath aesni_intel snd_seq_device crypto_simd mac80211 cryptd glue_helper joydev drm_kms_helper dell_wmi rtsx_pci_ms ipmi_devintf dell_smbios intel_cstate ipmi_msghandler dcdbas snd_timer memstick intel_rapl_perf input_leds drm sparse_keymap wmi_bmof serio_raw intel_wmi_thunderbolt dell_wmi_descriptor cfg80211 mei_me mxm_wmi snd processor_thermal_device i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea intel_rapl_common sysfillrect soundcore mei libarc4 sysimgblt intel_pch_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal dell_rbtn acpi_pad acpi_thermal_rel mac_hid nf_log_ipv6 ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack sch_fq_codel
[  585.267920] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to recalculate rts/cts prot for vdev 0: -108
[  585.267924] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set cts protection for vdev 0: -108
[  585.267929] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set erp slot for vdev 0: -108
[  585.267933] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to set preamble for vdev 0: -108
[  585.267937] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to down vdev 0: -108
[  585.267942] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to submit vdev param txbf 0x0: -108
[  585.267945] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: failed to recalc txbf for vdev 0: -108
[  585.518538] ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: device successfully recovered
```

and

```
iwconfig

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

enp59s0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp60s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"VM1523314_EXT"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 08:36:C9:05:51:2C   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

and

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

and

```
journalctl -p err -b 

-- Logs begin at Sun 2019-10-06 21:45:30 BST, end at Thu 2020-01-30 17:42:09 GMT. --
Jan 30 16:53:35 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
Jan 30 16:53:51 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: This service starts and stops VMware services.
Jan 30 16:54:05 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 gdm-password][2948]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Jan 30 16:54:13 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 mailnag[3506]: ERROR (2020-01-30 16:54:13): Failed to open mailbox for account 'masterbogdandirbg@gmail.com (Gmail)' ([AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)).
Jan 30 16:55:14 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 libvirtd[1621]: Device 0000:02:00.0 not found: could not access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/config: No such file or directory
Jan 30 16:55:55 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: PCI post-resume error -19!
Jan 30 16:55:55 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:39:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
Jan 30 16:58:44 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 wpa_supplicant[1407]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: firmware crashed! (guid e0db7bbf-9872-4b3c-b90f-625d2aac258d)
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: firmware register dump:
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [00]: 0x05030000 0x00000000 0x00950A7C 0x0059CB04
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [04]: 0x00950A7C 0x00070030 0x00000000 0x000A68A8
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [08]: 0x004479B4 0x004481A6 0x00080805 0x0040E788
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [12]: 0x00000000 0xFFFFFFFF 0x00952CD0 0x00952CE6
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [16]: 0x809A9637 0x0040E788 0x00404D00 0x2A05C000
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [20]: 0x00000002 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x0046E7B8
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [24]: 0x809ED6BF 0x0040E7C8 0x00423C1C 0xC09ED90B
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [28]: 0x009ED90B 0x00060330 0x00000000 0x2A0BD3C0
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [32]: 0x0044AC60 0x0040E7E8 0x00000002 0x0059CAF8
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [36]: 0x00000003 0xFFFFFFFF 0x00952CD0 0x00952CE6
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [40]: 0xDD36F468 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x000A68A8
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [44]: 0x809EC16A 0x0040E7F8 0x00000010 0x00423C1C
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [48]: 0x809EA597 0x0040E7E8 0x0044819E 0x00000000
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [52]: 0xDD36FA38 0x0049E860 0x00000001 0x004127C0
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [56]: 0x809EC88D 0x0040E868 0x0041293C 0x0044841C
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400  11  11   3   3
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800   4   4 113 114
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00  31  31  94  95
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000  14  14  16  14
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 4439 4431 231 169
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800   0   0  64   0
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00  30  30  17  17
Jan 30 16:59:11 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:3c:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000   1   1   1   1
Jan 30 17:01:17 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 wpa_supplicant[1407]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Jan 30 17:01:49 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 wpa_supplicant[1407]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Jan 30 17:03:18 bogdan-Alienware-17-R3 wpa_supplicant[1407]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu, what release? The 5.4 kernel doesn't match any stable ubuntu release.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am on Ubuntu 19.10. I have been manually updating my kernel to the latest stable version (every few weeks) for a few years now, as when I initially bought the laptop I had some driver issues that were resolved later.

Comment: Using mainline kernels is not supported on Ubuntu. Try to boot with an Ubuntu kernel and test if you have the issue there.

Comment: @Pilot6 Booted into `5.3.0-29-generic` and the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

There is a newer firmware file available that might help

```
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0
sudo mv firmware-6.bin firmware-6.bin.bak
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin
sudo mv board-2.bin board-2.bin.bak
sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/raw/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
```

Reboot

If this newer firmware makes it worse, you can revert to the older by

```
cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0
sudo mv firmware-6.bin.bak firmware-6.bin
```

Comment: I already have the newest firmware as I have said in the question

Comment: firmware ver WLAN.RM.4.4.1.c3-00059 api 6 that is what your info told us and that is older firmware version

Comment: that file is 3 months old and is the most recent one I can see on the git repository

Comment: There is a board-2.bin file there that is only 4 hours old now.  If you look at the commits you will see the firmware version I lnked to replaced the one you are using

Comment: Oh, sorry the first time you wrote you talked about the firmware file only. I did try the brand new (4-5 hours ago) board-2.bin file just before installing my new wireless card (I updated the question) and it didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

It might help someone. I've solved my really awful problem of QCA6174 adapter's disconnecting and intermittent wifi in Ubuntu 18.04.5, just by upgrading to the newest kernel, 5.11.6. Before resorting to that, I had tried almost every recipe in the internet with no success.

Answer (score -1):

The [QCA6174](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Qualcomm_Atheros_QCA6174) hardware is designed for [5 GHz band only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ac) and 2.4GHz networks will not see its signals.

Comment: the only network on which I have stable connection (the one I am on now) is 2.4 GHz. Also, as I said, I have used this laptop for years without problems and I am sure I have connected to networks with both 5GHz bands and 2.4GHz bands