# Wifi barely works on 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04

I have recently had trouble with wifi on my laptop. Specifically, wifi will connect but the connection is highly unstable. Downloading any file or loading more than a simple site often fails. Toggling wifi off/on restores the connection for a moment.

The problem started while I was running 21.10. I upgraded to 22.04, but the problem persisted. Eventually, I tried a clean install of 22.04. Following various posts here, I have tried numerous kernel versions. I have disabled power saving. I have tweaked modprobe settings. Unfortunately, after several reinstalls etc, I don't have all the links. But for now I'll keep the list below updated.

- [change kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388115/how-do-i-update-my-kernel-to-the-latest-one/1388117#1388117)
- [powersave](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403773/22-04-wifi-keeps-disconnecting-for-a-few-seconds-frequently)

Edit: I am on a Dell XPS from ~2016.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Rivet Networks Killer Wireless-n/a/ac 1535 Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
```

```
$ uname -r
5.15.0-25-generic
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: A starting point is to identify your wireless hardware. Each hardware needs its own drivers and/or settings. Applying random "wireless" solutions can only make things worse.

Comment: It should work well. It is likely to be a hardware problem (a detached antenna, etc)

Comment: Thanks for your help. What makes you confident that it should be working well?

Comment: I was worried that it could be hardware.

Comment: The device is well supported by kernel.

Comment: How do you know/check that?

Comment: It is a QCA device.

Comment: Sorry...I don't have a ton of experience with matching hardware/firmware/kernels. How can I check this for myself in the future?

Comment: There is no fixed way. You need a ton of experience literally.

Comment: But there is a chance that this a problem with ath10k firmware, a very small one. I would try to check hardware first.

Comment: Any easy way to check the hardware? People seem to have trouble with QCA6174 and ath10k going back years: https://askubuntu.com/questions/607707/ath10k-installation

Comment: This repo seems recently updated: https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware

Any chance things like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206902/19-10-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-wifi-works-on-one-network-out-of-many would work for me?